# How is Mint on VirtualBox configuring ethernet?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

Unlike many questions in which people need help with something that isn't working, I'm trying to understand how something *is* working, when the stuff that I've read suggests it shouldn't be.  I have working network adapters, so to speak, which aren't referenced in Mint / Ubuntu / Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  I anticipate needing to make some changes, but I'm hesitant to mess with it without understanding what's going on now.

Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit installed on the real hardware.

I have VirtualBox v 5.0.10 installed thereon ("VBox").

Into VBox, I installed Mint v. 17.3, without event or hassle - amazing enough in itself!

In VBox's configuration for the Mint VM, I defined two virtual Ethernet devices.  From `VBoxManage showvminfo`, they are:

```
NIC 1:           MAC: 0800270E9166, Attachment: NAT Network 'natnet1', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 2:           MAC: 080027D0A390, Attachment: Host-only Interface 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
```

As I understand it, this simply makes it appear to any code running in VBox that there are two ethernet adapters; configuring them within the VM must happen in the usual way.  The "usual way," as I understand it,in a Debian family Linux distro, is to put some entries into `/etc/network/interfaces` to specify that they're to be started upon boot, how they get their addresses (DHCP or explicit), and so on.

Here is what I have on the Mint system:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0e:91:66  
          inet addr:172.24.100.4  Bcast:172.24.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0e:9166/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:186069 (186.0 KB)  TX bytes:26524 (26.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d0:a3:90  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed0:a390/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:71869 (71.8 KB)  TX bytes:23154 (23.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17039 (17.0 KB)  TX bytes:17039 (17.0 KB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:6b:ec:12:b7:d4  
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::746b:ecff:fe12:b7d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8834 (8.8 KB)
```

Aside from `lo`, how are the others getting configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Mint is using the NetworkManager daemon to manage its interfaces. If you didn't change anything in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` or in the GUI network setup, the `/etc/network/interfaces` is not taken into account.

The default option `managed=false` in the `NetworkManager.conf` file makes that any interfaces listed in the `/etc/network/interfaces` will be ignored.

In a console, type `nmcli con list` to list the interfaces managed by NetworkManager.

See `man nmcli` for more options.